# How do I write sql subquery in codeigniter active record?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is in select sub query and join sub query. The query is as below.

```
SELECT t1.BranchId,t1.BranchName,FORMAT(TotalRevenue/total_trans,2) AS Average,t1.ReadingDate 
    from (SELECT br.BranchName,
    count(nooftrans)as total_trans,zf.BranchId,ReadingDate,zf.zread_id 
    FROM `ospos_zreads_pdf` zf , ospos_branches br,ospos_zreads_pdf_activity_status zpf 
    WHERE br.BranchId = zf.BranchId and zf.zread_id=zpf.zread_id and ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and zpf.zreadactivity='Sales Transaction'
    group by zf.BranchId)t1 
    join (SELECT br.BranchName,sum(TotalRevenue)as TotalRevenue,zf.BranchId,zread_id,ReadingDate 
    FROM `ospos_zreads_pdf` zf , ospos_branches br
    WHERE br.BranchId = zf.BranchId and ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    group by zf.BranchId)t2 on t1.zread_id=t2.zread_id
```

Comment: Read [this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) to be aknowledged how to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable protection on some of db methods with a second parameter:

```
$this->db->select('id, title, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM other) as count', FALSE)
```

More in the documentation:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html